# Android: To maintain chronometer timing between the activities

Tags: android

There are three buttons in class A and class B.CheckIn,Cancel,Complete. Click on one of these buttons leads to corresponding activity in the class B.I am saving the current time in the chronometer in a database with the help of Helper class once in a minute.But I want to continue run the time even I go to the other activities. But I am getting the latest updated time while I was in the Activity.So is there is any solution to run the chronometer even I switch between the activities?? Thanks In advance!!!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkin_timer);
    taskId=getIntent().getIntExtra("taskId", 1);
    status=getIntent().getIntExtra("status", 0);

    String values1[]={Integer.toString(taskId)};
            //Helper class retrieves the time spent with given parametrs
    System.out.println(Helper.getfromUrl(getTimeSpentUrl,values1));
    timeSpent=Long.parseLong(Helper.getfromUrl(getTimeSpentUrl,values1));


    chrono=(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chrono);
    btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnCheckIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);
    btnComplete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnComplete);

    chrono.setText(formatTime(timeSpent));
    System.out.println(timeSpent);

    chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener()
    {

       public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           time++;
           if(!resume)
                    {
                     currentTime=formatTime(timeSpent+SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-chrono.getBase());
                     arg0.setText(currentTime);
                     elapsedTime=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+timeSpent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     currentTime=formatTime(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase());
                     arg0.setText(currentTime);
                     elapsedTime=elapsedTime+1000;
                    }
           if( time== 60 )
           {
               String values2[]={Integer.toString(taskId), Long.toString(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase())};
               String updateTime=Helper.getfromUrl(updateTimeUrl,values2);
               if (!updateTime.equals("success"))
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               time=0;
           }
       }
    });
    if(status==0)
    {
        flag=1;
        this.onClick(btnComplete);
    }
    else if(status==1)
    {

        this.onClick(btnCheckIn);
    }
    else if(status==2)
    {
        flag=1;
        this.onClick(btnCancel);
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(v.getId())
  {   
    case R.id.btnCheckIn:
       btnCheckIn.setEnabled(false);
       btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
       if(!resume)
               {
                chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chrono.start();
               }
               else
             {
                 chrono.start();
               }
       String values[]={Integer.toString(taskId),Integer.toString(1)};
       String updateCheckIn=Helper.getfromUrl(updateCheckinUrl, values);
       if (!updateCheckIn.equals("success"))
       {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       }
       break;
    case R.id.btnCancel:
       btnCheckIn.setEnabled(true);
       btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
       chrono.stop();


       String values1[]={Integer.toString(taskId),Integer.toString(0)};
       String updateCheckIn1=Helper.getfromUrl(updateCheckinUrl, values1);
       if (!updateCheckIn1.equals("success"))
       {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       if(flag==1)
       {

           chrono.setText(formatTime(timeSpent));
       }
       else
       {
           resume=true;
           chrono.setText(formatTime(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase()));
           String values2[]={Integer.toString(taskId), Long.toString(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase())};
            String updateTime=Helper.getfromUrl(updateTimeUrl,values2);
            if (!updateTime.equals("success"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
       }
       flag=0;
       Intent reasonIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Reason.class);
        startActivity(reasonIn);

       break;
    case R.id.btnComplete:
        btnCheckIn.setEnabled(false);
        btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
        chrono.stop();
        resume=true;

         String values11[]={Integer.toString(taskId),Integer.toString(0)};
         String updateCheckIn11=Helper.getfromUrl(updateCheckinUrl, values11);
         if (!updateCheckIn11.equals("success"))
         {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }


         String values3[]={Integer.toString(taskId),Integer.toString(1)};
         String updateComplete=Helper.getfromUrl(updateCompleteUrl, values3);
         if (!updateComplete.equals("success"))
         {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         if(flag==1)
           {

               chrono.setText(formatTime(timeSpent));
           }
           else
           {
         chrono.setText(formatTime(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase()));
         String values21[]={Integer.toString(taskId), Long.toString(elapsedTime-chrono.getBase())};
         String updateTime1=Helper.getfromUrl(updateTimeUrl,values21);
          if (!updateTime1.equals("success"))
         {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
           }

         Intent completeIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CompletionStatus.class);
         startActivity(completeIn);
         finish();
          break;

    }
}
 public String formatTime(long millis) {
     String output = "00:00:00";
     long seconds = millis / 1000;
     long minutes = seconds / 60;
     long hours = minutes / 60;

     seconds = seconds % 60;
     minutes = minutes % 60;
     hours = hours % 60;

     String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
     String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
     String hoursD = String.valueOf(hours); 

     if (seconds < 10)
       secondsD = "0" + seconds;
     if (minutes < 10)
       minutesD = "0" + minutes;
     if (hours < 10)
       hoursD = "0" + hours;

     output = hoursD + " : " + minutesD + " : " + secondsD;
     return output;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setBase()` is used to set the time that the count-up timer is in reference to.
. You need to hold on to this value somewhere outside the activity, like in the `Application` class. Whenever your activity has resumes, you `setBase()` to this reference time.

Comment: +1 i am your follower,can you please tell me what to do (read/watch) to know more about android as you do.! thanks..learnt a lot from your answers.

Comment: Suppose I am keeping the base in  a field in a database.. What modification has to be done??

Comment: It does not make sense to make a db to store one value. [Use SharedPrefrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) and store it as a `long`

Comment: no,I already have a db in my application. Db is needed to store different tasks and their base times.. I still have some logic error..Pls help me with a pseudo code..