# How to continue the timer (started in activity1) after activity2 is started?

Tags: android

I start a timer in `activity1`. And in the timer task, I run some code continuously for a long time. Then I sometimes need to start `activity2` like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(Tomato.this, History.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But then error occurs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: timer-1
```

Could anyone help?

**Further:**

I tested again, and found that this error didn't occur every time. Now I cannot even repeat it. 
Thanks for all of you!

Comment: Show more code, what line is giving you that exception?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061300/android-to-maintain-chronometer-timing-between-the-activities

Comment: For what did you need the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I run some code continuously for a long time"

This is usually when you decide that this code should run in a service. Check out the Service SDK documentation and you'll get an example of local Service.

If the timer is just something you need to access accross activities, you could implement a singleton that will hold one instance of it.